# Simulator turns black

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, simulator

I am new to programming and am trying to make an app. My problem now is that when I start the simulator, the app doesn´t show, only black and the battery/time row on the top. I have tried reseting the simulator, cleaning the program, and many other things from other conversations but nothing worked. What could be the problem?

I can insert the coding lines that you need to figure it out.

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn
import Firebase


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}
var window: UIWindow?







func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
FIRApp.configure()

self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var ViewController: ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleController") as! ViewController

self.window?.rootViewController = ViewController

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


var configureError: NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self




GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID




// Initialize sign-in
return true





    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                 annotation: annotation)

    }
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        } else {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["statusText": "Signed in user:\n\(fullName)"])
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }

        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!,
                  withError error: Error!) {
            // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["statusText": "User has disconnected."])
            // [END_EXCLUDE]


    }

}
```

Storyboard:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn
import Firebase


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}
var window: UIWindow?







func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
FIRApp.configure()
return true
self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var ViewController: ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleController") as! ViewController

self.window?.rootViewController = ViewController

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
var configureError: NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

return true





GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID




// Initialize sign-in

return true





    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                 annotation: annotation)

    }
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        } else {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["statusText": "Signed in user:\n\(fullName)"])
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }

        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!,
                  withError error: Error!) {
            // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["statusText": "User has disconnected."])
            // [END_EXCLUDE]


    }

}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}}
```

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise its just wild guessing.

Comment: what codes do you need?

Comment: Your initial view controller should be a good start, plus any configuration you may have done in a `storyboard`/`xib`

Comment: I have posted both the view controller and app delegate if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem lies in your `AppDelegate`. It seems that you have multiple `return` statements in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method - the execution won't reach the parts after the first one. So your view controller instantiation won't be reached. Simply remove all `return` statements, except the last one, and everything should work.

Comment: I have now tried that but it did not work. I updated the appDelegate in the question, is there something there I forgot?

Comment: Why are you doing this - `self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)`? The window should be initialized by the system for you.

Comment: That was something another conversation said could help if the simulator was black, but is didn't help for me so maybe I should delete it. But the problem came before I inserted that.